# How to simplify this binary-to-java-type code?

Tags: java, casting, bit-shift

I get two java bytes as input that together symbolizes a 16-bit signed integer. I need to convert it to one single java integer (signed, of course). I have come up with a "ugly" solution, that includes converting to an int, then to a short and then back to an int. Is there a shorter and more elegant way?
My code is as following:

```
public int convert(byte b1, byte b2){
    int i1 = (int) (((b2 << 8) + (b1 & 0xFF)) & 0x0000FFFF);
    short s1 = (short) i1;
    int i2 = (int) s1;
    return i2;
}
```

Comment: `return (short) i1;` would be simpler, making use of automatic widening.

Comment: But I must get an int (not short) in the end (for legacy reasons).

Comment: `return (short) i1;` is identical to your last 3 lines. Pinky swear.

Comment: Also, you don't need the explicit cast in the `int i1 = (int) ...` line. The `<<`, `+` and `&` have already promoted everything to `int`.

Comment: No, return (short) i1 casts i1 to a short. It will giva a compiler error since the function signature tells it must returns an int.

Comment: "return (short) i1 casts i1 to a short" It casts `i1` to a short, and then immediately widens it back to an int to return it. [This compiles just fine](https://ideone.com/BVFRsx).

Comment: Ok. Anyway there seems to be no way to avoid the int-short-int roundtrip.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to match your converter - not certain it is simpler but it is certainly less verbose.

```
public int convert2(byte b1, byte b2) {
    return new BigInteger(new byte[]{b2,b1}).intValue();
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution, will try. I forgot to mention that performance is not unimportant. I need to convert TONS of these numbers in real time.

Answer (score 1):

The following is equivalent:

```
return (short) ((b2 << 8) | (b1 & 0xFF));
```

`byte` has a small enough range that it is practical to test this equivalence for all possible values of `b1` and `b2`:

```
byte b1 = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
do {
  byte b2 = Byte.MIN_VALUE;
  do {
    assertEquals(convert(b1, b2), convertEquivalent(b1, b2));
  } while (b2++ != Byte.MAX_VALUE);
} while (b1++ != Byte.MAX_VALUE);
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/rVJq0K)

Answer (score 0):

@AndTurner is probably the solution you sought.

However if a byte array or some file channel (memory mapped file), input stream is involved, one may use a ByteBuffer.

```
byte[] bytes = ...
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
...
short n = buf.readShort(); // Sequential
short m = buf.readShort(354L); // Direct access
```